# installing gazebo_ros_pkgs for groovy

Tags: ros, gazebo-1.9, groovy

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

today i tried to reinstall `gazebo` and `gazebo_ros_pkgs` following the current instructions. Gazebo compiles and runs without any problems. but when i tried to compile `gazebo_ros_pkg`s I ran into a couple of problems.

**1st** missing shared objects in the precompiled ubuntu package

when I called catkin_make to compile the `gazebo_ros_pkgs` there where at least one missing .so file:

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgazebo_sdf_interface`

so i tried compiling from src witch leaded to other problems

**2nd** rosdep installs gazebo-prerelease

the command `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy -y` installs

*gazebo-prerelease* and *sdformat* debian packages.

this should probably not happen...
but can be easily undone, with `apt-get remove`...

**3rd**
when I try to run `catkin_make` I get an error about redefinition of classes.

`In file included from /usr/local/include/gazebo-1.9/gazebo/sdf/interface/SDF.hh:25:0, from /usr/local/include/gazebo-1.9/gazebo/sdf/sdf.hh:21, from /usr/local/include/gazebo-1.9/gazebo/physics/State.hh:26, from /usr/local/include/gazebo-1.9/gazebo/physics/ModelState.hh:30, from /usr/local/include/gazebo-1.9/gazebo/physics/Model.hh:31, from /usr/local/include/gazebo-1.9/gazebo/physics/Actor.hh:24, from /usr/local/include/gazebo-1.9/gazebo/physics/physics.hh:2, from $HOME/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins/include/gazebo_plugins/gazebo_ros_block_laser.h:37, from $HOME/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_block_laser.cpp:26: /usr/local/include/gazebo-1.9/gazebo/sdf/interface/Param.hh:50:9: error: redefinition of ‘class sdf::Param’ /usr/include/sdf-1.4/sdf/Param.hh:52:9: error: previous definition of ‘class sdf::Param’`

currently I don't know how to fix this problems. I would be happy if some one could point me in the right direction...

Thx

Benjamin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3595/installing-gazebo_ros_pkgs-for-groovy/) by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 881 on 2013-07-16

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EduardoMaciel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/270/eduardomaciel/) on 2013-07-17**:
In your ~/catkin_ws/build/CMakeCache.txt, add the following code (search INTERNAL cache entries): https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6022853 - try again catkins_make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi again,

after switching to the branch gazebo_1.9 the old error disappeared and now i get an error about a missing SDF.hh header and a lot of other things

`/home/user/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_bumper.cpp:31:22: fatal error: sdf/SDF.hh: No such file or directory compilation terminated. /home/user/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_camera_utils.cpp:34:22: fatal error: sdf/SDF.hh: No such file or directory compilation terminated. /home/user/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_block_laser.cpp:31:22: fatal error: sdf/SDF.hh: No such file or directory compilation terminated.`

I'm currently confused how this can compile on other installations...

a lot of plugins seem to include `<sdf/SDF.hh>` (for example `gazebo_ros_block_laser.cpp`)
but neither gazebo nor sdformat seems to have a file in this path
gazebo has `<sdf/interface/SDF.hh>` and sdformat has no SDF.hh.

when using the SDF.hh from gazebo catkin was trying to use the sdf includes from gazebo...

after further investigations I recognized that gazebo is not using any of the src in the gazebo/sdf  directory anymore, so removed the gazebo sdf directory in my include path and replaced all occurrences of sdf/SDF.hh with sdf/sdf.hh

this seems to have solved the Problem. I'm not sure how this is supposed to work

I will now do some tests with my current solution and mark the Question as solved if no unexspected behaviour occurs....

---

Originally posted by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) with karma: 881 on 2013-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EduardoMaciel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/270/eduardomaciel/) on 2013-07-18**:
In your ~/catkinws/build/CMakeCache.txt, add the following code (search INTERNAL cache entries): https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6022853 - try again catkinsmake.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2013-07-25**:
this might be an error from intermediate releases, can you try
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gazebo
to install latest gazebo 1.9.0 and try catkin_make again from scratch?  This should have been fixed.

**Comment by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) on 2013-07-26**:
@hsu Hi,

the SDF.hh error is definitively fixed in the repo...

I am not sure about the copied directory of the current gazebo-src realease...
but I guess the files aren't copied anymore. I don't know if this Problem occurres when using the precompiled gazebo-prerealese version...

maybe I try to install everything from source again next week but I'm not sure if I find the time for that.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

OK so I've also updated all my source repositories, and had to fix the missing SDF.hh error which seems
to be due to the SDF repository removing the file SDF.hh. So I changed the includes in the files
gazebo_ros_block_laser.cpp, gazebo_ros_bumper.cpp, and gazebo_ros_camera_utils.cpp to

```
#include <sdf/sdf.hh>
```

Then I still get the *redefinition of ‘class sdf::Param’* error. How is this supposed to work? Should
Gazebo even have a Param.hh file in its source repo? Here are the latest source files:

Latest version of gazebo/physics/State.hh
https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/dd765457ec03337cf12fa75ce8327674e6c8d79c/gazebo/physics/State.hh?at=default
includes "gazebo/sdf/sdf.hh"

Latest version of gazebo/sdf/sdf.hh
https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/dd765457ec03337cf12fa75ce8327674e6c8d79c/gazebo/sdf/sdf.hh?at=default
includes "gazebo/sdf/interface/Param.hh"

groovy-devel branch version of /gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins/include/gazebo_plugins/gazebo_ros_block_laser.h
https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/groovy-devel/gazebo_plugins/include/gazebo_plugins/gazebo_ros_block_laser.h

```
#include <sdf/Param.hh>
```

- which is the conflicting file from /usr/include/sdformat-1.4/sdf/Param.hh
  rather than "gazebo/sdf/interface/Param.hh"

Output of normal catkin_make run:

```
Built target gazebo_plugins_gencfg
Scanning dependencies of target gazebo_ros_camera_utils
[ 70%] Building CXX object gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/gazebo_ros_block_laser.dir/src/gazebo_ros_block_laser.cpp.o
[ 70%] Building CXX object gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/gazebo_ros_bumper.dir/src/gazebo_ros_bumper.cpp.o
[ 70%] Building CXX object gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/gazebo_ros_camera_utils.dir/src/gazebo_ros_camera_utils.cpp.o
In file included from /home/zeyn/Dropbox/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_bumper.cpp:32:0:
/usr/include/sdformat-1.4/sdf/Param.hh:52:9: error: redefinition of ‘class sdf::Param’
/usr/local/include/gazebo-1.9/gazebo/sdf/interface/Param.hh:52:9: error: previous definition of ‘class sdf::Param’
In file included from /usr/local/include/gazebo-1.9/gazebo/sdf/interface/SDF.hh:25:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/gazebo-1.9/gazebo/sdf/sdf.hh:21,
                 from /usr/local/include/gazebo-1.9/gazebo/physics/State.hh:26,
                 from /usr/local/include/gazebo-1.9/gazebo/physics/ModelState.hh:30,
                 from /usr/local/include/gazebo-1.9/gazebo/physics/Model.hh:31,
                 from /usr/local/include/gazebo-1.9/gazebo/physics/Actor.hh:24,
                 from /usr/local/include/gazebo-1.9/gazebo/physics/physics.hh:2,
                 from /home/zeyn/Dropbox/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins/include/gazebo_plugins/gazebo_ros_block_laser.h:37,
                 from /home/zeyn/Dropbox/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_block_laser.cpp:26:
/usr/local/include/gazebo-1.9/gazebo/sdf/interface/Param.hh:52:9: error: redefinition of ‘class sdf::Param’
/usr/include/sdformat-1.4/sdf/Param.hh:52:9: error: previous definition of ‘class sdf::Param’
/home/zeyn/Dropbox/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_bumper.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::GazeboRosBumper::Load(gazebo::sensors::SensorPtr, sdf::ElementPtr)’:
/home/zeyn/Dropbox/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_bumper.cpp:78:43: error: ‘class sdf::Element’ has no member named ‘Get’
/home/zeyn/Dropbox/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_bumper.cpp:78:58: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
/home/zeyn/Dropbox/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_bumper.cpp:78:60: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
/home/zeyn/Dropbox/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_bumper.cpp:85:44: error: ‘class sdf::Element’ has no member named ‘Get’
/home/zeyn/Dropbox/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_bumper.cpp:85:59: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
/home/zeyn/Dropbox/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_bumper.cpp:85:61: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
/home/zeyn/Dropbox/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_bumper.cpp:95:56: error: ‘class sdf::Element’ has no member named ‘Get’
/home/zeyn/Dropbox/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_bumper.cpp:95:71: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
/home/zeyn/Dropbox/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_bumper.cpp:95:73: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
In file included from /home/zeyn/Dropbox/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_camera_utils.cpp:35:0:
/usr/include/sdformat-1.4/sdf/Param.hh:52:9: error: redefinition of ‘class sdf::Param’
/usr/local/include/gazebo-1.9/gazebo/sdf/interface/Param.hh:52:9: error: previous definition of ‘class sdf::Param’
```

Output of verbose catkin_make run:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c91bac3148ae5a96dec1

The only other thing is that I'm not quite up-to-speed with Catkin, and its possible I've got my environment in a muddle. My settings are:

```
zeyn@limivorous [~/catkin_ws] echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
/usr/local/lib/gazebo-1.9/plugins:/usr/local/lib:/home/zeyn/Dropbox/catkin_ws/devel/lib:/home/zeyn/catkin_ws/devel/lib:/opt/ros/groovy/lib

zeyn@limivorous [~/catkin_ws] echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH 
/home/zeyn/Dropbox/catkin_ws/src:/home/zeyn/Dropbox/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks
```

(note that ~/catkin_ws is a symlink to ~/Dropbox/catkin_ws)

---

Originally posted by [Zeyn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/424/zeyn/) with karma: 11 on 2013-07-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) on 2013-07-18**:
@Zeyn look at my answer I did nearly the same thing but removed the gazebo sdf directory. This solved the Problem for me...